# Custom authentication in ASP.net Core 2 for API

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-2.0

I am developing an API using ASP.Net Core 2. To authenticate, the web app is passing the Bearer token in header of the request. I would like to know the best practice in ASP.Net Core 2 to authenticate by passing the token via request.

Comment: https://auth0.com/blog/securing-asp-dot-net-core-2-applications-with-jwts/

Comment: Thank you very much @OffDutyBlue